# Xamarin.Android app using fragment, how to bind a handler on a widget within a fragments

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

My app is using Bottom Navigation, is as 3 tabs. The fragments are created at startup by supportFragmentManager. The first fragment (tab) is shown to the user. I want to hook a button handler on a button on the third fragment (3rd tab).

The app has only one activity. From this activity, in the OnCreate method, and after creating the 3 fragments, I call

```
myButton= FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.theButton);
```

The code run, but since myButton is always null I can't hook a handler to it! Like if the UI is not yet ready for this fragment, since it is showing the first one currently.

Is there another event where I can hook the handler ? I can't add the handler form within the fragment's code neither. Always get a null!

Comment: Can you add your code for each fragment!

Comment: You can try to write an interface to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've started from scratch a test project to try to pinpoint the problem, I didn't overused copy paste in order to have a fresh solution. And, strangely, that test solution is working. Surprised ? Not really I guess!

But in order to explain to anyone who might experienced the same problems I did experiment, here what the symptoms were and how I fixed it.

When I used the view in the OnCreateView method of the fragment like this:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_options, null);

        myButton = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.Button1);
        myButton.SetOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
```

view.FindViewById always returned Null, even if in the intellisense, "Resource.Id.Button1" was there and autocompleted!

Turn out that Button1 was defined as follow on the layout file of the fragment

```
<Button id="@+id/Button1" 
    android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
    android:text ="Test"
/>
```

and not as

```
<Button android:id="@+id/Button1" 
    android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
    android:text ="Test"
/>
```

as it should have been. A properly named "id" attribute!

The end result was that "Button1" was indeed in the resource file, and hence "intellicompleted" but not properly namespaced! And, yes, there was compiler warnings that I should have looked more closely. The warnings did oriented me to the problem.

So the problem was behind the keyboard! Hope this explanation to be of some help to anyone as goofy as I!